# Binarization for very dark image

Tags: image-processing

I have many very dark images, I want to binarize these images, I used partial Ostu, but the result is terrible.

This is the image of night plate

[image]

and after partial Ostu, the result

[image]

So there are solutions to solve my problems?

Comment: crap in = crap out. you cannot segment the letters with threshold operations if you have such a terrible SNR. you should rather improve your image quality befor you invest any time into processing.

Comment: However, my task is to find the way to binarize these images, sad!

Comment: I have difficulties reading this myself. I guess the only chance you have is something that does not need the entire character to be present which might become pretty error prone. template matching or machine learning maybe.

Comment: How many of those images do you have? And do you know in advance what they say? Because if so, you can use machine learning to *learn to process* those images.

Comment: you know there is a reason why radar traps usually come with a flash :)

Comment: @Imanol Luengo, I use the faster-rcnn find those plates in the whole dark image, so I believe use the cnn may can solve this issue, but I have no idea now(:

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is virtually impossible. Too low SNR and uneven illumination (or dirt).

I tried different denoising approaches, adaptive thresholding, combined with equalization or not, to no avail.

[image]

Barely readable, even for humans.

Comment: can you share the approach you obtain the bottom image, I think most images can be seen by eye, just needing great effort, and I use the faster-rcnn finding the position of those cropped plate in the whole dark image, so I wander it can be done by the cnn or other machine learning approaches, but I have no idea now :)

Comment: This is equalization. Note that it does not improve the "binarizability" at all.